# How do I access javaws within the Install4j bundled JRE?

Tags: java, java-web-start, install4j

I have created an application using Install4j, and I need to run javaws from the bundled JRE. I can use ${launcher:sys.jvmHome} to get to the jre folder, which contains a bin folder. I thought javaws would be there, but it isn't. Do I need to do something else to include javaws in the JRE, or am I looking in the wrong place entirely? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javaws is excluded from the pre-made bundles for install4j. You can create your own bundles by invoking

Project->Create a JRE bundle

from the main menu. Those bundles will include javaws.